# Как запаковать body для подписи в post запрос?

Tags: python, api, post

Почему не работает post запрос?

```
api_path = "/v3/order/cancel"
nonce = str(int(time.time()*1000.0))
body = json.dumps({"order_id": 1000000})
msg = api_path+nonce+body
kun_signature = hmac.new(secret_key.encode('ascii'), msg.encode('ascii'), hashlib.sha384).hexdigest()
headers = {'accept': 'application/json',
'content-type': 'application/json',
'kun-nonce': nonce,
'kun-apikey': public_key,
'kun-signature': kun_signature}
responses = requests.post( url , headers=headers).json()
print(responses)
```

Выжимка из библиотеки.
Наименование метода /v3/order/cancel
Тип запроса POST
Пример body для отмены одного ордера

Пример запроса

`{"order_id": 1000000}`

Он ругается, что подпись некорректная.
`{'messages': ['signature_is_incorrect']}`

Дело, однозначно в `body`. Поскольку, если не требуется тело запроса, то отправляю `body = str('')` и все работает нормально. Но в данном случае, для отмены ордера требуется подобное `body`

Comment: Вы забыли отправить body. Подпись-то создали, а прикрепить body к запросу забыли.

Comment: Это как? В data его запихать?

Comment: Да. . . . . . .

Comment: Благодарен! Спасибо!